# how to get my home network ip address write it to a file automatically

Tags: ip-address

im running a windows xp xampp 1.6.6 server and i need to get it online for testing purposes and for my friends to test their code on

so i was thinking of getting my router ip address and save it to a file or write an index.html with the address to open it from google drive web hosting or whatever its called

so is there a way to get my ip address maybe make an auto refresh page on chrome with the search what is my ip address and somehow get the result on the first box that appears or is there any shell command i can use to get it (ipconfig does not show the router ip)

Comment: ipconfig does give your ip address (look in the IPv4 Address section)

Comment: ya that isnt a thing in windows xp

Comment: and while i try to do ipconfig /renew it says :An error occurred while renewing interface Wireless Network Connection 2 : unabl
e to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection while it has its media disconnected.